# AWS Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://rekognition.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I'am trying to use aws rekignition but I get a error "Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://rekognition.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/"

My request is: 
aws rekognition detect-labels --image "{\"S3Object\":{\"Bucket\":\"jramirezneira2\",\"Name\":\"Screenshot_1.jpg\"}}" --region eu-west-3

I'will really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to service availability doc, Rekognition is not offered in Paris region:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/